# HAPROXY to proxy HTTPS traffic

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I have a VPC on AWS that includes a NAT instance for outgoing traffic. This NAT instance is associated with an EIP provided by AWS. Some EC2 instances on the VPC access an external service via HTTPS. I'm looking for a way to access this service via a HAPROXY but I'm not able to make it work.

The service is accessed via HTTPS so the proxy sends CONNECT requests to the service which responds with 404. I guess the service is not configured to accept such requests.

Is there another way to configure HAPROXY so that it works?

The configuration I use:

```
global
 daemon
 maxconn 256
 log 127.0.0.1:514 local0 debug
 chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
 pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid

defaults
 mode tcp
 option tcplog
 log 127.0.0.1:514 local0 debug

frontend proxy_in
 bind <LOCAL_IP>:8443
 mode tcp
 option tcplog
 log 127.0.0.1:514 local0 debug
 default_backend proxy_out

backend proxy_out
 mode tcp
 log 127.0.0.1:514 local0 debug
 option log-health-checks
 server server1 <REMOTE_HOSTNAME>:443 ssl check verify none
```

When using HTTP mode, I can see the following:

```
Dec  6 11:01:07 localhost haproxy[23393]: <IP>:41729 [06/Dec/2020:11:00:17.107] proxy_in proxy_out/proxy_out 0/0/24/19/50045 404 3588 - - cD-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "CONNECT <REMOTE_HOSTNAME>:443 HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: What is your current configuration? What do the logs show?

Comment: @Tommiie I edited the question.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with HAPROXY but it looks like you're trying to use HAPROXY as a simple TCP bouncer. I don't think you should be using "ssl" mode in your server directive in the backend, instead you should just make a regular TCP connection so that HAPROXY is completely unaware of SSL, and SSL just runs directly between the client and the server, with HAPROXY being not involved in that.